# Jquery html in tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip

I have a simple jQuery tooltip script:

http://jsfiddle.net/FFHnm/

it pulls the title tag in the link in the following line:

```
var title = jQuery(this).attr('title');
```

And inserts it into the tooltip in this bit:

```
.text(title)
```

Is it possbile to add html like a h2 to the `title` variable like so:

```
.text("<h2>" + title + "</h2>")
```

Thank you any help would be appreciated as i am very new to jQuery :)

Comment: Using `html` method, yes.

Comment: Side note: Refer to [demos](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style) and [api](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/); you do not need to use `.hover()` and `.mouseover()` to control tooltip. Example: in place of `.mouseover()`, you can simply use [`track` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-track).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using .text() you can use .html(), then you can set HTML as you are describing.

```
 .html('<h2>' + title + '</h2>);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct, just change:

```
jQuery('<p class="ttip"></p>')
```

to

```
jQuery('<h2 class="ttip"></h2>')
```

in your javascript.